# Home Fibernetwork setup vs Traceroute results - where is my WAN IP located?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, modem, isp

On my learning with using traceroute, I have actually put it to practical use with my current home network setup trying to figure out what are the available hops and IPs assignment but have encountered several doubts which I have no answers to and hope that gurus here can advise further..

Below is the setup diagram that I have got from my ISP website, I have added in where I suppose my workstation will be sitting at the right bottom.

[image]

Below are my traceroute results (myrepublic.com.sg = my ISP)

[image]

---

So I have come to the conclusion that

1. The 1st hop IP address 192.168.1.1 is assigned to an "internal" interface in the router on the diagram.
2. 172.20.0.1 is on the interface at the modem.
3. Interface C will be so call the WAN port on the router whereby i should plug the connection to/from the modem.

---

These bring me to the following questions below and I will really appreciate if anyone can shed some light on it.

1. Is my assumption above correct ?
2. does modem interfaces have IP (172.20.0.1) ? - i am thinking that modem is just a layer1 or 2 device to change signals format though..
3. if yes, is there anyway we can find the IP on the interface C?
4. what is the IPs of interface A and B as shown in the diagram above  (is 103.6.148.4 shown in the 3rd hop on the traceroute result above on any these interfaces ?)
5. Last for not least, the most confusing part to me is that I have bought a static public IP 101.100.172.157, which interface is it actually assigned on ? Interface C ? (but isn't Interface C a point to point connection with the modem interface @ 172.20.0.1 ?)

Did I get anything wrong or my understanding of traceroute is wrong...
Hopefully, gurus here can give me some advises ~_~

---

Thanks for replying.

> 1. Is my assumption above correct ? – 2. 172.20.0.1 is on the interface at the modem.
>
> No, most likely it will be the next hop beyond your modem (I'm
>   guessing it will be the ONT, as explained below).

But the modem i am referring to is the ONT which is where i am labelled 172.20.0.1 (on the ONT modem interface port 2) -- are we referring to the same thing ?

> 3. if yes, is there anyway we can find the IP on the interface C?
>
> Try connecting to the router over SSH, or over Telnet, or even to its
>   web interface over http. If it's not severely locked down, it should
>   show
>
> Alternatively, since the ONT seems to have 172.20.0.1 on its LAN
>   interface, it will likely have assigned something from 172.20.0.* to
>   your router. Try pinging 172.20.0.2 and see if you get a response.

I can only connect to the router via 192.168.1.1 (through http)
I try pinging 172.20.0.2 to 172.20.0.10 to no avail. Accessing 172.20.0.2 via web is unreachable also.

Any other way I can find the IP on interface C ? It should be in the same subnet as 172.20.0.1 right ?

> "Interface B", the ONT's WAN interface, will have your external IP
>   address assigned to it.
>
> *Last for not least, the most confusing part to me is that I have bought a static public IP 101.100.172.157, which interface is it
>   actually assigned on ? Interface C ? (but isn't Interface C a point to
>   point connection with the modem interface @ 172.20.0.1 ?)*
>
> As above, it is assigned to the interface that directly faces your ISP
>   – in your case that's the ONT's "interface B".
>
> But if the ONT was acting purely as a bridge, then it would be the
>   router's "interface C", as is usually the case with ADSL.

When i connect to the router at 192.168.1.1, it can detect and is showing its own WAN IP as 101.100.172.157. But if the WAN is set at Interface C, how does it explain the connection between Interface C to the ONT Interface (172.20.0.1); they should be in the same subnet isn't it ?

If the WAN is set at Interface B, (ignoring the TP), the next hop is 103.6.148.45), is 103.100.172.157 and 101.100.172.157 in the same subnet then ?  and if it is set as Interface B, how does my router know its own WAN IP ?

Please advise.

Regards,
Noob

Comment: Hi Grawity, I just reverted questions to your post as below. Please take a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*(Corrections would be appreciated)*

> 1. Is my assumption above correct ? – 1. The 1st hop IP address 192.168.1.1 is assigned to an "internal" interface in the router on the diagram.

Yes. Most likely it's assigned to a virtual "bridge" interface, which joins together the "ethernet" and "wlan" interfaces.

(It could be multiple ethernet interfaces (one per port) bridged at OS level, or it could be a single interface for the entire multi-port switch; it varies.)

> 1. Is my assumption above correct ? – 2. 172.20.0.1 is on the interface at the modem.

No, most likely it will be the next hop beyond your modem (I'm guessing it will be the ONT, as explained below).

Purely internal hops (between interfaces of the same device) generally won't show up on traceroute. So you will only see the IP address from the interface "on your side".

> 1. Is my assumption above correct ? – 3. Interface C will be so call the WAN port on the router whereby i should plug the connection to/from the modem.

Yes.

> 2. does modem interfaces have IP (172.20.0.1) ? - i am thinking that modem is just a layer1 or 2 device to change signals format though..

It varies. Dial-up modems were mostly that. A plain fiber⇄ethernet media converter would also be layer 1 only.

But ONTs like yours, as well as ADSL "modems", do a bit more. They're actually very similar to your WiFi router, in that there's an Ethernet interface (or even a switch) plus other media that needs special handling and configuration, and an embedded OS that bridges them together (or routes between them).

For example, a WiFi access point has to know its SSID, send beacons, manage associated clients. Connecting to a "PicoStation" AP over SSH and running `ip link` will show a bridge `br0` linking together `eth0` and `wlan0` interfaces.

An ADSL modem needs to know the ATM VPI/VCI, and perhaps talk PPPoA or even PPPoE over the ATM circuit. It will similarly have `atm*` interfaces for each ATM circuit, as well as virtual Ethernet-over-ATM interfaces, and will usually act as a NAT router between ATM WAN and Ethernet/WiFi LAN.

And while I've had *very little* experience with fiber ONTs (and only the GPON kind; I'd appreciate edits here), they also seem to have some sort of link setup/handshake & customer identification, and sometimes even NAT & port-forwarding settings.

So they all boil down to the same general structure, just different media.

> 3. if yes, is there anyway we can find the IP on the interface C?

Try connecting to the router over SSH, or over Telnet, or even to its web interface over http. If it's not *severely* locked down, it should show

Alternatively, since the ONT seems to have 172.20.0.1 on its LAN interface, it will likely have assigned something from 172.20.0.* to your router. Try pinging 172.20.0.2 and see if you get a response.

> 4. what is the IPs of interface A and B as shown in the diagram above (is 103.6.148.4 shown in the 3rd hop on the traceroute result above on any these interfaces ?)

The TP *is* a plain layer-1 converter, so "Interface A" will not have any address – it's just a dumb port going to your ISP's network. But according to your traceroute, it eventually leads to a router having address 103.6.148.45.

"Interface B", the ONT's WAN interface, will have **your external IP address** assigned to it.

> 5. Last for not least, the most confusing part to me is that I have bought a static public IP 101.100.172.157, which interface is it actually assigned on ? Interface C ? (but isn't Interface C a point to point connection with the modem interface @ 172.20.0.1 ?)

As above, it is assigned to the interface that directly faces your ISP – in your case that's the ONT's "interface B".

But *if* the ONT was acting purely as a bridge, then it would be the router's "interface C", as is usually the case with ADSL.

(And with ADSL, if the ADSL modem was also acting as a pure bridge, then the computer itself could obtain that external address. This used to be common with ADSL ~10 years ago, and it's how dial-up worked too.)

---

Note that a single interface *could* have multiple IP addresses, though that's rare.

---

> But the modem i am referring to is the ONT which is where i am labelled 172.20.0.1 (on the ONT modem interface port 2) -- are we referring to the same thing ?

No, I accidentally thought the router was the 'modem'.

> When i connect to the router at 192.168.1.1, it can detect and is showing its own WAN IP as 101.100.172.157. But if the WAN is set at Interface C, how does it explain the connection between Interface C to the ONT Interface (172.20.0.1); they should be in the same subnet isn't it ?
>
> If the WAN is set at Interface B, (ignoring the TP), the next hop is 103.6.148.45), is 103.100.172.157 and 101.100.172.157 in the same subnet then ? and if it is set as Interface B, how does my router know its own WAN IP ?

Can't really answer that without being able to directly take a look at the devices' configuration... It could be that the router uses UPnP to detect this. It could be that it *does* in fact own the WAN IP. It could have *both* the WAN IP address and an 172.* address on the same interface. The above description was just the simplest option out of possible ones.

Comment: Hi Grawity, I just reverted questions in to your answer in my original post, please check back~